# How to add DNS server in icinga/nagios server on ubuntu?

Tags: server, nagios3, dynamic-ip

I already install and configure icinga on ubuntu.All host configure IP in manually.Now I want to add DNS in my icinga server. Actually, I want to add that keep to dynamic IP address in host. Now all the host IP is dynamic that why my icinga server does not working properly. Because every time host IP is changed. After that all host is down. This is a big problem in my icinga server. How to I configure DNS or Dynamic IP address in icinga server. Please given solution.

Comment: Configure your DNS server to reserve IPs for your hosts instead of messing around in Icinga.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to re-think your network Topology find an IP range that works for your hardware and assign all devices individual Static IP's generally speaking only clients should use Dynamic convention unless all devices are dynamic.

Comment: whom ever is going around down voting everyone without reading the entirety of the question is quite frankly being childish. Johors English may not be perfect but he was clear enough for me to understand that he needed some help. Johor please go to my question and +1 it so its out of the negative range Ill do the same for you.